# How to include custom type converter using Maven and Grails

Tags: maven, grails

I am working on a Grails project that needs to compile with both Grails and Maven. Everything worked great except for my GSON converter I added (using the grails-gson plugin). Now I get the following when I run mvn install.

```
 unable to resolve class grails.plugin.gson.converters.GSON
```

Anyone know how to overcome this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin has to be added as a dependency in `pom.xml` too

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.4</version>
  <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

Mavenized grails project refer pom file for all dependencies (including plugin dependencies).

Comment: One more question though, I had to edit the project is there a way to install into maven from grails?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the question.

Comment: So the plugin project (GSON) I have edited it and I want to install the new version into the Maven repo. Is there an easy way to do this other than manually zipping the file and installing it using mvn install:install-file?

Comment: Yes there is an easy way. Grails plugins use [grails release plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/release) for publishing. I suppose you hve a  forked instance of GSON plugin on which you have worked on. You just need to call [`grails maven-install`](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-release/docs/manual/guide/maven.html) (from release plugin) which packages and publishes the plugin in you local maven repo. I hope this exactly what you are looking for. BTW, if it is defect you have worked on in the plugin, you can raise a github issue and submit a pull request.